# How to schedule reports in HP Project and Portfolio Management Center 9.12?

Tags: project-management

I use hp project and portfolio management center 9.12

I have several reports, some are running every day, but other not. Where I can look and change setting for schedule running reports?

Comment: Is this a web application? If not, you're better off asking at [su]

Comment: yes, it's web application: HP Project and Portfolio Management (PPM) is web-based software that provides visibility into strategic and operational demand, resource productivity and utilization, and associated financial information across a portfolio. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hewlett_Packard_Enterprise_Software

Comment: "Web-based software" doesn't necessarily make it on-topic here. When you think "web apps" think Facebook, Twitter, Google Spreadsheets. If it's self-hosted it's probably off-topic here. (Note the lack of a tag for this app, for instance.)

Comment: @AL, from http://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour: Web Applications is a question and answer site for power users of web applications. Is it web application? Yes. But anyway, if it isn't appropriate here, just remove this question.

Comment: I think I have a pretty good idea of the site's scope. In any event, I'm merely questioning whether it belongs or not. If I was certain, I would have voted to close already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open this web application.
2. Menu: Open -> Reports -> View Reports
3. Select Report Type and click “Search” button.
4. You see list of reports. To sort them by date to see last reports, click on Run Date header.
5. Click on Submission Details.
6. If you want to reschedule this report, click “Copy”
7. Enter details and click “Submit”